# Espresso: String in adapterView

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Is ist possible with android-espresso to verify, if a string is shown in one of more items of a listAdapter?

Trying somethiong like this:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.test)).check(matches(hasToString("Anmeldung steht noch aus!")));
```

Comment: You mean entire list item matches the test string?

Comment: yes, i wanna check if at least one item contains this string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This must work but only based on list item position:

```
onData(instanceOf(YourListItem.class))
  .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.test))
  .atPosition(0)
  .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Anmeldung steht noch aus!"))));
```

If you want to check that the unique text is present somewhere in the adapter - you should create your own matcher, so, it will be something like:

```
onData(withYourListItemText("Anmeldung steht noch aus!"))
  .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.test))
  .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

and matcher:

```
public static Matcher<Object> withYourListItemText(final Matcher<String> yourListItemText) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(yourListItemText);
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, YourListItem>(YourListItem.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(YourListItem item) {
            return yourListItemText.matches(item.getYourItemText());
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with text: " + yourListItemText.toString());
            yourListItemText.describeTo(description);
        }
    };
}
```